Visibility of old Q/A on home page
I would like to discuss the sense of have old Q/A to be pushed to the home page of SE sites. Here is a case when the Q/A is interesting but it is asked 14 years ago. And by the rules of ServerFault must be closed.

Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices.
Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms
or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

I understand it is not answered (accepted answer) but the rules said....
Maybe this practice (to push old Q/A to home page) should stop or the list of pushed Q/A to be filtered.
About filtering: AFAIK the way of registering Windows do not change much so this Q/A (IMHO) have value for readers (event it is about windows 2012 which is out of support)

I understand it is not answered (accepted answer)
An upvoted answer stops questions from being pushed to the front page

@user9517, thank you for clarification.

Seems like noone from users, moderators, management have something to say...

Technically this is a dupe of https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8422, https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9691, https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1223 and probably others.

@user9517, IMHO all of them discuss the community bot which bump questions. But I did not saw any of them to go deep in to the contradiction i mention in the this question.
